# Shade area under a function curve with 2 variables

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this function of 2 variables:

```
match = (2.*x-1).*y.^(.1) - 2.*x.*y;
```

Plot using `ezplot(match, [0 1], [0 1])` yields:

[image]

I would like to shade (fill) the area under this green curve all the way to the 2 axis. I have tried to get the x and y data via `get(h,'XData')` and `get(h,'YData')`, and then use

```
area(x,y)
```

but the plot is not correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Essentially by using EZ plot on similar domains you create two identical ranges for each variable, essentially only plotting match = f(x). Is this what you want? Why use two variables in that case?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am trying to plot the zeros of match, i.e., match == 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option:

Assuming that you have a **match()** function:

```
function z = match(x,y)

z = (2.*x-1).*y.^(.1) - 2.*x.*y;

end
```

And you use **ezplot()**:

fig = ezplot('match', [0 1], [0 1]);

[image]

The following code extract the data from the figure and plot the area:

```
h1 = findall(fig,'Type','hggroup');
matrix = get(h1,'ContourMatrix');
xData = matrix(1,3:end);
yData = matrix(2,3:end);

area(xData,yData)
xlim([0 1])
ylim([0 1])
```

[image]

The key point is that **ezplot()** uses a contour object, therefore it is a little more trickier to get the data.

Comment: One more thing: Instead of filling, how can I hatch the area?

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean with 'hatch the area'?

Comment: Instead of a solid fill, I would like to have stripes going across the area.

Comment: The downside of EZplot is that you cannot control the accuracy though (i.e. number of points plotted).

Answer (score 1):

OK, a rather inefficient solution is by using the symbolic toolbox:

```
syms y
match = @(x) (2.*x-1).*y.^(.1) - 2.*x.*y;

n = 100;
xs = linspace(0,1,n);
yval = zeros(n,2);

for ii=1:n
    x=xs(ii);
    temp = solve(match(x),'y', 'Real', true);
    if length(temp)==1
        yval(ii,1) = temp;
    elseif length(temp)==2
        yval(ii,:) = temp;
    end
end

area(xs,yval(2))
```

Mind that the first solution is always '0'. I don't know if performance is an issue but this might be working for you!